# How to get a specific section of JSON into a string?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm new to JSON, node.js and javascript... I have a small node.js server that fetch a JSON object(named weatherData below) from openweathermap.org and I'm trying to make it display only a specific part of the JSON object(a section called "temp"). So far I used:

```
var tempString = JSON.stringify(weatherData);
```

And then I used search and substring methods of string to get my info but there's got to be an easier way right? How do I only display the temp section without using string methods?

EDIT: When I stringify the whole thing I get this

> "{\"coord\":{\"lon\":-75.7,\"lat\":45.41},\"sys\":{\"type\":3,\"id\":119304,\"message\":0.0297,\"country\":\"CA\",\"sunrise\":1413804390,\"sunset\":1413842906},\"weather\":[{\"id\":802,\"main\":\"Clouds\",\"description\":\"scattered
>   clouds\",\"icon\":\"03n\"}],\"base\":\"cmc
>   stations\",\"main\":{\"temp\":273.05,\"humidity\":84,\"pressure\":1012.188,\"temp_min\":273.05,\"temp_max\":273.05},\"wind\":{\"speed\":1.11,\"deg\":260.506},\"rain\":{\"3h\":0},\"clouds\":{\"all\":44},\"dt\":1413780770,\"id\":6094817,\"name\":\"Ottawa\",\"cod\":200}\n"

Comment: Why don't you do `JSON.stringify(weatherData.temp);`?

Comment: This is completely backwards.  You have the data in javascript object form where you can directly access all the parts.  You do NOT want to stringify it and turn it into an easter egg hunt to find what you want.  Show us what the JSON data looks like and point out exactly what you want out of the data.

Comment: I tried that but it prints "undefined". I thought this might be because it's not actually called temp but if I print the whole JSON it displays something like this: 

{\"temp\":273.05,\"humidity\":84,\"pressure\":1012.188,\"temp_min\":273.05,\"temp_max\":273.05},\"wind\":{\"speed\":1.11,\"deg\":260.506},\"rain\":{\"3h\":0},\"clouds\":{\"all\":44},\"dt\":1413780770,\"id\":6094817,\"name\":\"Ottawa\",\"cod\":200}\n"

Comment: Please put the JSON in your question and format it properly (use the Edit feature).  Multi-line pieces of code are not very readable in comments.

Comment: It looks like maybe you're double stringifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON is already a native Javascipt object, but `weatherData.temp` is `undefined` because that's not one of the object's properties. What you want is nested under `main`:

```
weatherData.main.temp // 273.05
```

Since you mention you're new to JS / Node, it may be helpful to know about console.log() and util.inspect(). You can output an object to the console to inspect its structure using these tools.

Comment: For what it's worth, the distinction between JSON (Javascript Object Notation) and actual objects in Javascript can be confusing to newcomers. JSON is a text format for data interchange that closely resembles what is, in JS, known as an object literal. It mainly differs only in that it has a slightly restricted syntax. But most tools that import JSON data from an API will parse the JSON for you; you'll get a regular object back. What you get is no longer JSON, it just *was* JSON and *could be* JSON again.

Answer (score 1):

Its already is in JSON format, you don't need to convert it into a string.

You can access the "temp" section directly by using weatherData.temp

Answer (score 0):

have you tried?

```
var result = JSON.stringify(weatherData.temp);
```

Comment: Yeah I did but I get undefined when I do. I posted the result when I stringify the whole JSON in my OP.

Comment: hmmm.... JSON.stringify(weatherData.main.temp); will do.

you have to access each property in top-down order like going down the stairs.

For example: if you want to access c in a.b.c, you have to write the whole thing a.b.c, but not a.c.